# Hive error: return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.mapredtask

Tags: hive, mapreduce

I ran the following code in hive in windows-

```
 create database zomato comment ‘zomato database’ with dbproperties(‘Creator’=’Joe’, ‘date’=’2020- 11-02’);
    create external table zomato_details(restaurant_Id int comment ‘Restaurant id’, name string comment 
    ‘Restaurant name’, city string comment ‘Restaurant city’, location
    map<string,string> comment ‘Latitude and longitude of the restaurant’ ,cuisine array<string> comment 
    ‘cuisines available’ ,currency string comment ’currency accepted’, has_table_booking string comment
    ’yes or no field’, has_online_delivery string  comment
    ‘yes or no field’,price_range int  comment ‘range
    from 1-5’,rating_text string comment ‘good,very good excellent’,votes int coment ‘total votes’,) ;
    load data local inpath ‘C:\Users\Desktop\hive photo\zomato.csv’ into table zomato_details;
    create table partcity(restaurant_id int, price_range int) partitioned by(city String) row format delimited 
    fields terminated by ‘,’;
    insert overwrite table partcity partition(city) select restaurant_id, price_range, city from zomato_details;
```

Am getting an error in last command--

```
hive> insert overwrite table partcity partition(city) select restaurant_id, price_range, city from zomato_details;
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = L C Kumar_20201203191112_af4c5fc9-4e0d-4629-b78e-22f80d704ff7
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1607001298283_0003, Tracking URL = http://dnm-lt-lckumar:8088/proxy/application_1607001298283_0003/
Kill Command = H:\hadoop\bin\hadoop.cmd job  -kill job_1607001298283_0003
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2020-12-03 19:11:28,806 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1607001298283_0003 with errors
19:11:28.820 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-87] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task - Ended Job = job_1607001298283_0003 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
19:11:28.823 [Thread-80] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task - Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
19:11:29.006 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-87] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
19:11:29.066 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-87] ERROR org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation - Error running hive query:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:387) ~[hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:237) ~[hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$300(SQLOperation.java:90) ~[hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$2$1.run(SQLOperation.java:299) [hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807) [hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$2.run(SQLOperation.java:312) [hive-service-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_271]
19:11:28.820 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-87] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task - Ended Job = job_1607001298283_0003 with errors
19:11:29.006 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-87] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=2)
```

**I checked a lot but the logs are empty in the web application dashboard and even tried yarn logs and still couldn't find anything.**
I also tried various commands like--

```
**set hive.auto.convert.join=false;     
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;        
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;    
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=10000;    
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;**
```

but nothing worked for me
Can anyone please help me fix this error

Comment: Tracking URL = http://dnm-lt-lckumar:8088/proxy/application_1607001298283_0003/ check every failed container log.

Comment: I checked many times there are no container logs, it shows it's empty, and also couldn't find anything in the user log and temp folder .....